# Can scapy decrypt WPA2(802.11) on the fly?

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers

Long time ago i used netfilter_queue to create small program to monitor packets and block unwanted connections. So this program delays new connection by some time (miliseconds) and passing packets to userspace, but delay is perceptible when using firefox.

Next i figured out i can sniff packets and allow on the beginning all new connections to later block unwanted connections without delay. So everything would be fine, but when i switched to wifi network, **realized i need to decrypt wifi(wpa2) frame first, and i wonder if it is possible to do it in scapy?**

I'm looking something similar to [dot11decrypt](https://github.com/mfontanini/dot11decrypt) but in python.

Cant provide library i used before, it was not scapy, because its on another computer i don't have access right now. And i don't remember the name it was like 10 yrs ago. And sniffer was written in python module socket.

**EDIT:**

Now when i know scapy by itself can't decrypt WPA2 i found that there are tools written in python to [crack wpa2 password](https://github.com/k1nd0ne/ScapyWifi/blob/master/ScapyFi.py), so it should be possible to write program to sniff and decrypt WPA2 in python to get IP:PORT from packets.

But whole operation is not that strait forward. Need to know more about WPA2 protocol. Right now i don't have much time to do it but in spare time i will try to write something.

Comment: "i wonder if it is possible to decode 802.11 completely in python?" Well, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [look up](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+decode+802.11) an answer? Did you try [reading the documentation](https://scapy.readthedocs.io)? The splash page says right up front that one possible application is "injecting your own 802.11 frames"; so I would think it can decode them too. The [example of sniffing a packet](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#sniffing) shows "802.11" multiple times in the output, which also seems promising.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and try to *identify a specific problem*, showing the relevant code. It seems like you are already using the exact library for the job for one of its core purposes; so if for example "completely" means something special to you, we need to know specifically what information you are looking for and not getting from Scapy.

Comment: I red it, it can inject packets but there was nothing about decoding 802.11. English is not my first language so maybe i can't understand everything like native speakers. This question is simple because i need simple answer. I don't want to dig week and find that i can't do this in scapy.

Comment: See the example I linked of sniffing a packet? See what code it suggests using, and the resulting output? Is this not what you want? If it is not sufficient, then what exactly is missing?

Comment: Reading it right now.

Comment: You got me, i changed bolded question because it was misleading, i need to know if scappy can decode wpa2, so for example i will give sid and psk and scapy will show packets with ip:port protocol type etc ... what you linked it was sniffing packets only without processing (docoding wpa2) it further. But i found http://libtins.github.io/tutorial/802.11/ this tutorial so time not wasted not python but good info :) Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but there have to be place to pass password somewhere to get ip:port from 802.11 frame? And i cant find any example with password.

Comment: in WPA, psk == Pre Shared Key == password. `decrypt_proxy.decrypter().add_ap_data("my_secure_psk", "my_access_point_ssid");`

Answer (score 0):

So i dig, and dig, and I'm happy that i didn't stop.

**The answer is no, scapy can't decrypt WPA2(802.11).**

I had also used decrypt and decode word like they were the same words, my bad. So when i was talking about decode 802.11 i was talking about decrypting WPA2(802.11).

I just deduced reading EagleEye [paper](https://github.com/jordanhatcher/python-wpa2-cracker/blob/master/wpa2-cracker.py), their software uses dot11decrypt and libtins to do that and scapy to analyses data. I didn't have time to read whole paper, but think i understand their logic. Page 3 figure 1 have a nice picture.

I start digging again and their software is on [github](https://github.com/pmsosa/EagleEye), pretty nice software.

So that would be all. If I'm wrong correct me.